# TypeDef File Is Returning Undefined in Anglular CLI Test But Not In Real

Tags: angular, typescript

In the Handsontable typeDef file we can see...

```
export default class Handsontable extends _Handsontable.Core {
  static baseVersion: string;
  static buildDate: string;
  static cellTypes: _Handsontable.CellTypes;
  static Core: _Handsontable.Core;
  static dom: _Handsontable.Dom;
  static editors: _Handsontable.Editors;
  static helper: _Handsontable.Helper;
  static hooks: _Handsontable.Hooks;
  static plugins: _Handsontable.Plugins;
  static renderers: _Handsontable.Renderers;
  static version: string;
}
```

And in my Angular component I am trying to do this...

```
import Handsontable from 'handsontable';

export class ModelsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  console.log(Handsontable);
```

When I do `ng serve` then Handsontable is produced as...

```
Handsontable(rootElement, userSettings) {
  var instance = new _core2.default(rootElement, userSettings || {});

  instance.init();

  return instance;
}
```

But when I run `ng test` I get this...

`undefined`

Obviously I'm worried that Typescript (an apparently safe language) is returning two different things depending on what ran it. Can anybody explain what is going on and how to fix it?

p.s. I already tried...

```
import * as Handsontable from 'handsontable';
```

But that returned an error saying I could not instantiate that object with a constructor (when I put it with my actual code).

Answer (score 0):

Ok... this may sound stupid but, have you tried wrapping it in curly brackets? :-p

```
import { Handsontable } from './moreFilePathHere?/handsontable';
```

You may very well be able to write it like you have it, I've just never seen typescript imports written like that. In the code i've written/used, I only omit the curly brackets if I'm importing a standard JS library, or an entire file. In the Angular docs and elsewhere, whenever specific classes/interfaces are imported from a file that contains many of them, they are in curly brackets.

If that's not the problem, you may try simply moving it to its own type file and trying to import it from that. It's not really a solution but it will at least help you troubleshoot. I've had a lot of issues with exporting multiple interfaces from the same file. Oftentimes, it will compile OK, but I will get warnings/errors at runtime (and never before) saying that it can't find XYZ interface. I've even had this issue with some Angular core interfaces.

Also, this shouldn't really be a cause to your problem, but if that class is going to stay as is with no additional logic / methods, you may be better off using it as an interface rather than a class.